# Find a conformal map from disc onto trapezoidal plate

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> *how can conformal mapping a disk into a trapezoidal plate with defining   favorite central point?*

Comment: Do you think you could share any more details on your problem, and perhaps any code you have so far?

Comment: Do you know the Schwarz-Christoffel formula?

Comment: yes i know but i cant solve this.

Comment: Then can you please edit your question to show how you got stuck in applying Schwarz-Christoffel?